# Redirect to new page with path and optional argument in Flask and Flask-WTF not working

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask and Flask-WTF and I have the following code in my `views.py` file:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for   
from . import app, forms

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = forms.HelpSearch()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Searched for: %s' % form.value.data)
        redirect(url_for('help', form.value.data))
    return render_template('index.html', title='Index', form=form)


@app.route('/help/<keyword>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def help(keyword=None):
    form = forms.HelpSearch()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Searched for: %s' % form.value.data)
        redirect(url_for('help', keyword=form.value.data))

    # This is just some dummy data for testing my template
    keywords = ['n', 'north']
    groups = ['movement']
    syntax = [
        {'cmd':"n", 'args': ''},
        {'cmd':'north', 'args': ''}
    ]
    content = 'Move north'

    return render_template('show_help.html',
                            title=keyword,
                            form=form,
                            keywords=keywords,
                            groups=groups,
                            syntax=syntax,
                            content=content)
```

What I want, and expect, it to do is that when someone puts some text in the forms search field and hits the search button it returns that value and then I redirect to the appropriate page, e.g. they search for `foo` and end up at /help/foo.

Sadly the redirect from the form validation bit is not redirecting as desired. It just appears to be reloading the current page.

I know for a fact that the form is getting and returning the data because the `flash` call is showing up with the correct info, e.g. `'Searched for: foo'` but when I pass the keyword to `url_for` the page, again, simply reloads. Manually navigating to `/help/foo` works fine.

I have tested that `url_for` is working and it creates the appropriate path as desired when I enter a keyword manually, e.g. `print url_for('help', keyword='foo')` prints `/help/foo`.

Anyone have any idea why it is not redirecting as desired?

Edit: Got it running on [Heroku](http://mud-docs.herokuapp.com/) if anyone wants to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: Can you add the log of requests printed to your console?

Comment: @Miguel I am running it manually. However, this is what I get when I try searching with my form: `127.0.0.1 - - [18/Oct/2014 03:42:50] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`, or a `GET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is for not returning anything

you can check this:

```
def index():
    form = forms.HelpSearch()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Searched for: %s' % form.value.data)
        return redirect(url_for('help', keyword=form.value.data))
    return render_template('index.html', title='Index', form=form)
```

Comment: The form isn't? That's just it though, the data is there. The flash message shows the input given in the search box on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how you are doing your redirects. Instead of this:

```
redirect(url_for('help', keyword=form.value.data))
```

do this:

```
return redirect(url_for('help', keyword=form.value.data))
```

The `redirect()` function does not raise an exception like `abort()` does, it just returns a `Response` object that needs to be passed up the stack.

Comment: Holy... I cannot believe I left out the return. I am such an idiot.